# IBM Cloud DB2 on Cloud: Results window does not show in SQL Editor

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

I cannot see a result of an SQL query which I wrote and ran. I can export it, but I cannot see it. There is no magic arrow to open up 'Results' window either.

Help!
[image: Db2 on Cloud SQL Editor]

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same problem today, eventually figured out double-clicking on a query in the History tab opens the Results tab.

[image: IBM DB2 on Cloud History tab Results tab screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Next to **Export as csv** is a dropdown (see your and my screenshots). By default **Run all** is selected, but you can also choose to export to Microsoft Excel or only running selected (marked) queries.

[image: Db2 on Cloud run options]

Comment: Thank you, yes I can export the results of the query. But I'm not able to see results before I export. In other words - I don't have Results panes. Only the code panel and the history panel

Comment: Can't you change via the dropdown as described? What browser and version on which platform? Any add-ons that are blocking the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Select your query in History tab, Results tab will display next to it.